# If $m*n$ divides k, then both m divides k and n divides k

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

How might I complete this proof?

Let $(m*n)p = k$ such that p, m, n $\in$ Z. 
Then $m(n*p) = k$ and $n(m*p) = k$ thus n divides k and m divides k since $n*p$ and $m*p$ must also be integers. Therefore, if $m*n$ divides k, then both m divides k and n divides k.

Could I use the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic or Euclid's Lemma alternatively?

Comment: What do you mean $m,n$ don't have to be integers?  What does it mean to say that $m$ divides $k$ if $m$ is not an integer?

Comment: Does p*m have to be an integer to say that n divides k? @lulu

Comment: I deleted that comment of mine because I decided I didn't understand your question.  What does it mean to say that $m$ divides $k$ if $m$ is not an integer?

Comment: @MichaelRamageMikeRamage $m$ and $n$ have to be integers in order for $m$ and $n$ to divide $k$.

Comment: To be clear:  in my earlier (now deleted) comment, I assumed that $m,n$ were integers...without that assumption I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: If k=6.5 and m=21.5, so k*3=m. The equality still holds. @lulu

Comment: Every non-zero rational number divides every other rational number.  If you want to use a non-standard definition of "divides" you really need to tell us what you have in mind,

Comment: I have made a mistake. I apologize. @lulu

Comment: No need to apologize!  Is there a surviving question though?

Comment: I am curious if I can do this proof using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, perhaps. @lulu

Comment: Proof of what?  The question in the header doesn't make sense unless $m,n$ are integers (in which case it is trivial).

Comment: The only thing I can guess at is that you are asking:  "if $m,n\in \mathbb Q$ and $k\in \mathbb Z$ are such that there is $p\in \mathbb Z$ such that $p\times m\times n=k$ prove that there are integers $a,b$ such that $a\times m=k$ and $b\times n=k$" But this is obviously false.  Suppose $m=\frac 2{7}$, $n=\frac 72$ and $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is as follows:

Let *m*, *n*, and *k* be integers. Suppose that *mn* divides *k*. Then *k* = (*mn*)*p* for some integer  *p*. Note that neither *m* nor *n* can be equal to 0. Now, k = (*pn*)*m* and k = (*pm*)*n*, hence *m* divides *k* and *n* divides *k*.